# In $S_6$, let $\rho=(123)$ and $\sigma=(456)$. Find a permutation $x$ in $S_6$ such that $x\rho x^{-1}=\sigma$.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

In $S_6$, let $\rho=(123)$ and $\sigma=(456)$. Find a permutation $x$ in $S_6$ such that $x\rho x^{-1}=\sigma$.

My solution goes like this:

> We know that, if $\exists$ a permutation $\pi=(a_1a_2...a_n)$, then $\phi \pi\phi^{-1}=(\phi(a_1)\phi(2)\cdots \phi(n)).$ Using this result, $x\rho x^{-1}=\sigma\implies (x(1)x(2)x(3))=(456).$ But we need to consider $3$ cases: $(x(1)x(2)x(3))=(456),(x(1)x(2)x(3))=(564),(x(1)x(2)x(3))=(645).$ Thus, from these three cases:$x(1)=4,x(2)=5,x(3)=6\implies x=(14)(25)(36)$, $x(1)=5,x(2)=6,x(3)=4\implies x=(15)(26)(34)$ and for the third case, we have $x=(16)(24)(35).$ Thus, we have three solutions for $x$, i.e $$x=(14)(25)(36),(15)(26)(34)\space \text{or}\space (16)(24)(35).$$

Is the above solution correct? If not, where is it going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sigma$ can be described by the following:
$$4\rightarrow 5$$$$5\rightarrow 6$$$$6\rightarrow 4$$

You need to find a permutation $x\in S_6$ that does the following job:
$$4\overbrace{\xrightarrow{x}  1 \xrightarrow{(1,2,3)} 2 \xrightarrow{x^{-1}} }^{\sigma}5$$
$$5\overbrace{\xrightarrow{x} 2 \xrightarrow{(1,2,3)} 3 \xrightarrow{x^{-1}}}^{\sigma} 6$$
$$6\overbrace{\xrightarrow{x} 3 \xrightarrow{(1,2,3)} 1 \xrightarrow{x^{-1}}}^{\sigma} 4$$

Therefore, $x$ takes $4$ to $1$, $5$ to $2$ and $6$ to $3$. $$x=(1,4)(2,5)(3,6).$$

Comment: But is my solution and my reasonings correct?

Comment: Hmm, yes. It looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

The $x$'s you found don't move $1,2$ and $3$.  So $x\rho x^{-1}=\rho. $

You forgot about $\rho=(123).$

We just need $x(1)=4,x(2)=5,x(3)=6.$  So $x=(14)(25)(36)$ will work nicely.
This is because we have $x\rho x^{-1}=(x(1)x(2)x(3))=(456).$

No real need to get into cases.  Though if you do it you get two more solutions.   Namely $x=(15)(26)(34)$ and $(16)(24)(35).$

---

When you learn about the isotropy subgroup (in this case the centralizer), you'll see better why there's three.
In fact I think there's more than three.

Comment: Fixed the typos! Is my solution correct? Also are my reasonings correct? Forgive me, for making such stupid typos     

Comment: Now it looks right.

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

Let $\rho=(123)$ and $\sigma=(456)$ and form the young tableau
$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline 1&2&3\\\hline 4&5&6\\\hline\end{array}$ whose rows are these cycles respectively. Then $x=(14)(25)(36)$ obtained by columns of this tableau.

This works for all examples. For example, if $\rho=(123)$ and $\sigma=(356)$, form the young tableau
$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline 1&2&3\\\hline 3&5&6\\\hline\end{array}$ whose rows are these cycles respectively. Then $x=(13)(25)(36).$ Let's check:

$$x\rho x^{-1}=(13)(25)(36)(123)(36)(25)(13)=(1)(2)(356)(4)=(356)=\sigma$$
multplication being from left to right or from right to left (it doesnt matter).

Your solution is not visual enough. I always forget this rule: $\phi \pi\phi^{-1}=(\phi(a_1)\phi(2)\cdots \phi(n))$ and write it incorrectly.